# How to implement CCAvenue payment gateway option

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, payment, ccavenue

We need to implement [CCAvenue](http://www.ccavenue.com/) payment gateway  option.
How can I do this using ASP.net/C#?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the Integration Manual in ccavenue offical site.I hope it will help you

http://world.ccavenue.com/content/works_any_shoppingcart.jsp

Answer (score 1):

I have got it resolved. Yes CCAvenue provides good support. But the person who uses asp.net forum will always look for asp.net codes and direct answers. :)

I hope this will help someone. I have created two properties in code behind. One is to return checksum value and another one is to return details about the checkout items.

```
public string CCAvenueItemList
{
    get
    {
        StringBuilder CCAvenueItems = new StringBuilder();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtClientInfo = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["CheckedItems"];
        dtClientInfo = (DataTable)Session["ClientInfo"];
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            string amountTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Amount\" value=\"$Amount$\" />\n";
            string orderTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Order_Id\" value=\"$Order_Id$\" />\n";

            // BILLING INFO
            string billingNameTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_cust_name\" value=\"$billing_cust_name$\" />\n";
            string billingCustAddressTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_cust_address\" value=\"$billing_cust_address$\" />\n";
            string billingCountryTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_cust_country\" value=\"$billing_cust_country$\" />\n";
            string billingEmailTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_cust_email\" value=\"$billing_cust_email$\" />\n";
            string billingTelTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_cust_tel\" value=\"$billing_cust_tel$\" />\n";
            string billingStateTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_cust_state\" value=\"$billing_cust_state$\" />\n";
            string billingCityTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_cust_city\" value=\"$billing_cust_city$\" />\n";
            string billingZipTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billing_zip_code\" value=\"$billing_zip_code$\" />\n";

            billingCustAddressTemplate = billingCustAddressTemplate.Replace("$billing_cust_address$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString());
            billingCountryTemplate = billingCountryTemplate.Replace("$billing_cust_country$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString());
            billingEmailTemplate = billingEmailTemplate.Replace("$billing_cust_email$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["Email_ID"].ToString());
            billingTelTemplate = billingTelTemplate.Replace("$billing_cust_tel$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["Phone_no"].ToString());
            billingStateTemplate = billingStateTemplate.Replace("$billing_cust_state$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["State"].ToString());
            billingCityTemplate = billingCityTemplate.Replace("$billing_cust_city$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["City"].ToString());
            billingZipTemplate = billingZipTemplate.Replace("$billing_zip_code$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["ZipCode"].ToString());

            strAmount = dt.Rows[i]["INR"].ToString();
            amountTemplate = amountTemplate.Replace("$Amount$", dt.Rows[i]["INR"].ToString());
            orderTemplate = orderTemplate.Replace("$Order_Id$", dt.Rows[i]["ClientID"].ToString());
            billingNameTemplate = billingNameTemplate.Replace("$billing_cust_name$", dtClientInfo.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());

            CCAvenueItems.Append(amountTemplate)
                .Append(orderTemplate)
                .Append(billingNameTemplate)
                .Append(billingCustAddressTemplate)
                .Append(billingCountryTemplate)
                .Append(billingEmailTemplate)
                .Append(billingTelTemplate)
                .Append(billingStateTemplate)
                .Append(billingCityTemplate)
                .Append(billingZipTemplate)
                .Append(deliveryNameTemplate)
                .Append(deliveryCustAddressTemplate)
                .Append(deliveryCountryTemplate)
          }
        return CCAvenueItems.ToString();
    }
}
```

Another property to return checksum is

```
public string propcheckSum
{
    get {
        libfuncs objLib = new libfuncs();
        string strCheckSum = objLib.getchecksum("YourMerchantID", Session["ClientID"].ToString(), strAmount, "UrReturnUrl", "your working key");
        return strCheckSum;
    }
}
```

And used this property in design source view as like below

```
<div>
    <%=CCAvenueItemList%>
    <input type="hidden" name="Merchant_Id" value="yourmerchantID" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Checksum" value="<%=propcheckSum%>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Redirect_Url" value="YourWebsite'sThankyoupage.aspx" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" runat="server" />
</div>
```

You can get the merchant ID and generate the working key in CCAvenue website. That is in merchant login.

Hope this helps someone atleast.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to [signup first](https://www.ccnow.com/cgi-local/signup.cgi) or [contact them](http://www.ccnow.com/cgi-local/contact.cgi?partners) and ask for their payment integration manual. I don't think its same as integrating paypal in your website.