# How to integrate ccnow payment gateway in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, payment

How to integrate [ccnow](http://www.ccnow.com/) payment gateway in asp.net?
where can i get the activation key?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316430/how-to-implement-ccavenue-payment-gateway-option

Comment: @John Conde: This question is asking about CCNow, the other about CCAvenue.  They're extremely similar, but probably different enough to warrant a new question.

Comment: Close enough that I red them the same. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact CCNow support ( support@ccnow.com ) for your activation key, include your CCNow clientID.